# Running Time Analysis of a Simple Binary Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis

I'm stuck with the following problem by Skiena (The Algorithm Design Manual, p. 106):

> Problem: Give an efficient algorithm to determine whether two sets (of
>   size $m$ and $n$, respectively) are disjoint. Analyze the worst-case
>   complexity in terms of $m$ and $n$, considering the case where $m$ is
>   substantially smaller than $n$.
>
> Solution: First sort the big set – The big set can be sorted in
>   $O(n\log n)$ time. We can now do a binary search with each of the m
>   elements in the second, looking to see if it exists in the big set.
>   The total time will be $O((n + m)\log n)$.

My question: Why is the running time $O((n + m)\log n)$? I would have to perform m binary searches in total (one binary search for every element in $m$) - as one binary search has a running time of $O(\log n)$, I would have to perform $m \cdot \log n$ operations in the worst case. How does this - if at all - translate into $O((n + m)\log n)$?

Comment: It takes $O(n\log n)$ to sort the bigger set, and to $O(m\log n)$ to do the binary search, for a total of $O(n\log n + m\log n) = O((m+n)\log n)$. Note that you can do even better if you sort the smaller set instead, replacing $\log n$ with $\log m$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the big set takes time $O(n\log n)$. You perform $m$ binary searches, each taking $O(\log n)$, for a total of $O(m\log n)$ time spent on binary search. The total running time of the algorithm is thus
$$
O(n\log n + m\log n) = O((n + m)\log n) = O(n\log n),
$$
assuming $m \leq n$.

Note that it is even better to sort the smaller list, since then the running time improves to $O(n\log m)$.